# To extract a string from filename and insert it into the file

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I want to write a bash script for extracting a string from the file name and insert that string into a specific location in the same file.

For example:
Under `/root` dir there are different date directories `20160201`, `20160202`, `20160203` and under each directory there is a file `abc20160201.dat`, `abc20160202.dat`, `abc20160203.dat`.

My requirement is that I need to extract the date from each file name first, and then insert that date into the second column of each record in the file.

For extracting the date I am using

```
f=abc20160201.dat
s=`echo $f | cut -c 4-11`
echo "$f -> $s"
```

and for inserting the date iI am using

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "~"; ORS = "\n" ; date="20160201" ; IFS = "~"} { $1=date"~"$1 ; print  } ' file > tempdate
```

But in my `awk` command the date is coming in the first column. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

The file on which this operation is being done is a delimited file with fields separated by `~` characters.

Or if anybody has a better solution for this, please let me know.

Comment: You want the date after the existing `$1` value, so what you have as `$1=date"~"$1` should be `$1=$1"~"date` (or `$1 = $1 OFS date`), shouldn't it?  You can use `awk -v date="$s" '…'` to get the date into your `awk` script.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i tried using $1=$1"~"date but it takes the whole record as a string and appends the date at the end

Comment: @anubhava I was just trying the awk and by mistake i wrote the hard coded date script. It has to fetch the date from above and insert in the file

Comment: Then your input fields aren't delimited by `~` characters like you said they were.  Show us some example data (3 lines will be enough).

Comment: sample data: xyz~~0~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~0~0~~~~.00000000~.00000000~.00000000~~~~~

Comment: Click on [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35571016/edit) and provide sample data there.

Answer (score 0):

The variable for the input field separator is FS, not IFS. Consequently, the input line is not being split at all, hence when you add the date after field 1, it appears at the end of the line.

You should be able to use:

```
f=abc20160201.dat
s=$(echo $f | cut -c 4-11)
awk -v date="$s" 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "~" } { $1 = $1 OFS date; print }' $f
```

That generates the modified output to standard output.  AFAIK, `awk` doesn't have an overwrite option, so if you want to modify the files 'in place', you'll write the output of the script to a temporary file, and then copy or move the temporary file over the original (removing the temporary if you copied).  Copying preserves both hard links and symbolic links (and owner, group, permissions); moving doesn't.  If the file names are neither symlinks nor linked files, moving is simpler.  (Copying always 'works', but the copy takes longer than a move, requires the remove, and there's a longer window while the over-writing copy could leave you with an incomplete file if interrupted.)

Generalizing a bit:

```
for file in /root/2016????/*.dat
do
    tmp=$(mktemp "$(dirname "$file")/tmp.XXXXXX)")
    awk -v date="$(basename "$file" | cut -c 4-11)" \
        'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "~" } { $1 = $1 OFS date; print }' "$file" >"$tmp"
    mv "$tmp" "$file"
done
```

One of the reasons for preferring `$(…)` over back-quotes is that it is much easier to manage nested operations and quoting using `$(…)`.  The `mktemp` command creates the temporary file in the same directory as the source file; you can legitimately decide to use `mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/tmp.XXXXXX` instead.  A still more general script would iterate of `"$@"` (the arguments it is passed), but it might need to validate that the base name of the file matches the format you require/expect.

Adding code to deal with cleaning up on interrupts, or selecting between copy and move, is left as an exercise for the reader.  Note that the script makes no attempt to detect whether it has been run on a file before.  If you run it three times on the same file, you'll end up with columns 2-4 all containing the date.